# Custom permission level that cannot create sites

Tags: 2010, permissions, custom

In order to prevent users from creating sub-sites I created a custom permission level that identical to Full Control but has "Create sub-sites" unchecked. Turns out, users can still give them self or others Full Control, which then allows them to create a site.

What changes can I make to my custom permission level that will allow site owners to do just about everything except create a new site (and grant elevated permissions)?

By the way, we do not have access to the farm or Central Administration.

Comment: You'd need to deselect the manage permissions option in your custom permission level

Comment: Will that restrict people from granting permissions at all?

Comment: Yes, but it should still allow them to manage group membership for any groups they own. They just can't alter the group's underlying permissions as I recall. The last time I did this was in the 2007 days so I'm a little fuzzy.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `Full Control` or `Manage Hierarchy` permissions can create a subsite.

So try to take a copy from `contribute` permission level and try to customize it.

- Don't check `Create subsite` , `Manage website`.
- Check other roles based on your need one by one till get the correct permission that you need.